# String cannot be converted to JSONObject exception

Tags: android, json

Newbie to Json here, I'm gettin a  *Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject* error when I try and run the following code.I cant make any sense of other answers on here.

```
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
       JSONObject JN = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       String code =JN.getString("code");
       String message = JN.getString("message");
       if (code.equals("reg_true"))
       {
           showDialog("Your Registration has been successful.",message,code);
       }
       else if (code.equals("reg_false"))
       {
           showDialog("Your Registration Failed.",message,code);
       }


   } catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

This is the error

```
 W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
 W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
 W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:133)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:29)
```

Comment: What kind of string are you trying to convert in json? Can you show that ?

Comment: do a `Log.v("JSON",json);` copy and paste the json you get from the log here.

Comment: provide your json retrieved from server to analyze

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Its a registration form for an app, so I suppose its converting the registration input to json.@rusted brain Total newbie, where do i put that code?

Comment: @user1958789 just paste the value of `json`.

Comment: @user1958789 without your json data we can`t give correct answer..

Comment: @user1958789 write this `Log.v("JSON",json);` before `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);`

and the value will appear in the log from where you copied your error log.

Comment: delete first line `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);` and Follow tutorial http://terrapinssky.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-get-and-parse-json-file-from.html

Comment: is this your json looks like?
{
 "server_response": [{
  "code": "reg_true",
  "message": "abc"

 }, {
  "code": "reg_false",
  "message": "abcs"

 }]
}

Comment: @rusted brain this is what i get in log 50.665  t V/JSON﹕ Database connected....{"server_response[{"code":"reg_true","message":"Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy"}]}.                                                              So the info is going into database but the json issue appears to be with the dialog alerts for registering users and existing users, as in they are not being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json you are posting is invalid, trim that `{"server_response` and closing curly braces too. 
The remaining Json will be like this, which is valid now,

```
[{"code":"reg_true","message":"Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy"}]
```

**The you can parse it like here,**

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
String code = jsonobject.getString("code");
String message = jsonobject.getString("message");
```

**UPDATE :**

If your Json is as you commented then you can easily retrieve this like

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonarray = jobject.getJSONArray("server_response");
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
String code = jsonobject.getString("code");
String message = jsonobject.getString("message");
```

Comment: Am totally out of depth here , by trim {"server_response , what do you mean exactly?The server resopnse array is also part of the php code.

Comment: Is it the exact Json response are you posting ? It's really invalid. may you are pasting wrongly. Paste it again This kind of json won't be parsed.

Comment: .The json response using, Log.v("JSON", json);  from the server 

{"server_response":[{"code":"login_false","message":"Login Failed...Try Agin..."}]}.

Comment: tnxs for help , sorted it , the issue was in the php file,

Comment: @user1958789 As per your Json you commented parse like my answer's **update** section. If any issue left you can freely tell and  I will be glad if you mark it as correct if you think your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid. You can check your json on jsonlint.com
Correct json should be like this
`{"server_response":{"code":"reg_true","message":"Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy"}}`
Since you are using only one json object there is no need to create json array.

Remember if it starts with `[` and ends with `]` its json array; with curly braces `{...}` its json object.